# Black Screen at boot after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I perform an Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade from my Ubuntu 14.04. Everything went without issue but after restarting my computer I couldn't boot and were stuck in a black screen with an underscore ("_") blinking at the top-left corner.

I found many subject dealing with this kind of issue but nithing worked so far.
This is what I tried:

Can't access to Grub: I get the DELL splashscreen, after that I have a screen showing my harddrives and telling my that LSI ROM was successfully installed. I tried with Shift and Escape.
Ctrl + alt + F1 and Ctrl + Alt + F2 didn't work.

I tried to repair Grub with the boot-repair Live-USB but it didn't work either, in fact the live USB has the 14.04 version of Ubuntu and isn't available for 16.04.
I tried with a Live-Cd of ubuntu 16.04, I installed Boot-repair by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

It worked but when I tried to run the repair it's showing the following error: "Enable the repository containing the packages [grub2]  in the softwares' sources of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (sda1)"
So I went to Softwares' source Menu and I enable universe and multiverse then I typed sudo apt-get update.

But i didn't worked.
I tried to repair Grub with the SuperGrub liveCD I made with UnetBootin and a USB driver fromatted in FAT32. But after restarting the computer I can't launch the liveUSB: I get the UnetBootIn menu showing only one boot: Default and constantly reloading every 10 sc.

So I used the second method provided by doc.ubuntu:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1
```

But I get the following error:

> grub-install : attention : Le système de fichiers « ext2 » ne prend
>   pas en charge l'embarquage. grub-install : attention : L'embarquage
>   est impossible. GRUB ne peut être installé sur cette configuration
>   qu'en utilisant les listes de blocs. Cependant, les listes de blocs ne
>   sont PAS fiables et leur utilisation est déconseillée.. grub-install :
>   erreur : refus de continuer avec les listes de blocs.

In English It would be something like:

> Warning: the filesystem ext2 does not support "embarquage" (can't
>   translate this one) "Embarquage" is impossible. Grub can't only be
>   installed on this configuration using blocs'list (not sure...).
>   However the blocs'list aren't reliable and their using is not
>   recommanded  Error : refusal to continue using blocs'list.

I don't feel very safe to use the third method provided by doc.ubuntu (the chroot method) as the doc advertised that it could break the hard drive...

I prefer not to reinstall ubuntu 1-.04 as I don't want to loose some of my work.

I made a BootInfo Report:  [Report](http://textup.fr/211979Y7)

If you have any suggestion to make Boot-repair works, so I could repair my installation?

UPDATE: I commented the two lines: HIDDEN_TIMEOUT in grub, I updated it using chroot and now I can access to grub at boot now.
I tried the `nomodeset` option and `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` but the system still leads me to a black screen.

Comment: does it blink forever? have you tried waiting?

Comment: It seems to blink forever. I waited about 3 hours and nothing changed.
At the begining it shows me some message like "sda1 clean" but it is too fast for me to read. But there are only like three lines, maybe about mounting devices.
I will try to wait all  night and I will see tomorrow if I get something

Comment: in the grub menu press 'e' to edit the grub entry change 'splash' to 'nosplash' see if you can find the error.

Comment: It blinks forever.
ravery> I would like to but I can' access the grub menu unfortunately

Comment: On your `grub-install` command, try using `/dev/sda` rather than `/dev/sda1`. That's the source of your "filesystem ext2 does not support..." error message. ("Embarquage" translates as "embedding," BTW -- at least, that's the word that the English version of this message uses.) There are probably other ways around this problem, but that's what jumps out at me as one issue, and an easy fix, if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried it but unfortunately even if I installed grub correctly, boot-repair keps telling me that I have to enable the repository containing packages grub, I enable univers and multiverse I'm not sure what is the problem...
Thanks for the translation by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message translates as

```
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.
```

With the power of google I found this topic: [“warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329954/241355)

Two solutions are being proposed.

- First *solution* is to ignore it, since it is only a warning
- Second solution is to do a `grub-install /dev/sda` instead of
  `grub-install /dev/sda1`, just like Rod Smith proposed in the
  comment.

Comment: Ok, I tried this solution and, eventually, I installed grub without error message. I just tried the same line as before: `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1`
Unfortunately, I get the same message as before when I try to run Boot-repair: It's telling me to enable repository containing packages grub2...

Comment: I commented the two lines: HIDDEN_TIMEOUT in grub, I updated it using chroot andI can access to grub at boot now.